# How can I see function for sensor in 'ms5837-python' package

Tags: python, function, package, sensors

I have libraries for reading sensor chips for two a pressure temperature sensors.
One is ms5837 and this one works but I want to use ms5803.
import ms5837 works and also the line import 5803 works.

In using the ms5837 I can run the line
`sensor = ms5837.MS5837_BA()` and then do stuff.

I don't know the function entry names possible for ms5803:

- `dir(ms5837)`   produces
  `[__doc__','__loader__','__name__','__package__','__path__','__spec__']`
  no sign of the MS5837_BA() function
- `dir(ms5803)` gives the same result with no indication of the libraries available.

How can I list the function is either of these imports?

Answer (score 1):

Check [here](https://github.com/bluerobotics/ms5837-python). It is pretty straigh forward. At least with Raspberry PI. All

I2C sensors are more or less the same in this sense.

Comment: Using the sensor is straight forward if you know the internal functions. I know what the functions are for the ms5837 but I want to use another sensor the ms5803 but I don't know the function names. The python dir command doesn't show any functions for either sensor but the ms5837 obviously does have them and hopefully the ms5803. how can I illicit the function names?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am using a Raspberry Pi. Guilty!

The problem was with PYTHONPATH or in my case, python or the python program had to run in the directory with the ms5837 library that is downloaded.

After changing into the directory all the functions appear when using the dir(ms5837)   commend.

What was confusing to me was that the statement "import ms5837" worked and then the objects that should have come with that statemetn were not there.